# How to Make the Label and textbox on the same line

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

```html
    <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-6 ">
                    <h4>
                        <label class="">
                            The Money that you need is : @(HelpSeeker.money_needed= HelpSeeker.monthly_fees * HelpSeeker.month_count_needed) S.P
    
                        </label>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group-append col-md-2">
                    <span class="input-group-text"> $</span>
                    <span class="input-group-text"> 0.00</span>
                </div>
```

How can I make the label and the class "input-group-append" on the same line ?

This is the picture of the current output

Output:

[image]

Comment: you mean vertically center ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSS value like display:inline-block; , or display:flex; flex-direction: row;

Answer (score 0):

```
 .form-group{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: space-between;
   }
```

Try this